# How to fix Javascript code to be case sensitive in visual studio 2012

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, cross-browser

Recently I started modifying our website to be cross platform compatible. Our site was coded to work in IE 6 initially and upgraded to work IE7 then all code changes has stopped. The site was used in compatibility view until now. We are now changing the site to work for chrome, firefox, safari, and IE7(we have clients still using IE7 sadly) and above. 
Quickly we noticed the javascript coding wasn't coded to be case sensitive, this wasn't a problem with IE7 but now causes most pages to crash on chrome and others.

I am going page by page finding id's and doing updates to all codes to match same casing. But this is taking a lot of time and lots of checking on each page. 
I did a little search for a simpler way to fix these but could not find any solution. Is there a way to do this to all the files 100+ pages 1000's of lines of code. 
We are using studio 2012 pro. We are open for any other tool that can solve the issue.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: as in var string = String; ? just dupe all the ones you need to the case you need...